# How to find the minimal missing integer in a list in an STL way

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I want to find the minimal missing positive integer in a given list. That is if  given a list of positive integers, i.e. larger than 0 with duplicate, how to find from those missing the one that is the smallest.

There is always at least one missing element from the sequence.

For example given

```
std::vector<int> S={9,2,1,10};
```

The answer should be 3, because the missing integers are 3,4,5,6,7,8,11,... and the minimum is 3.

I have come up with this:

```
int min_missing( std::vector<int> & S)
{
  int max = std::max_element(S.begin(), S.end());
  int min = std::min_element(S.begin(), S.end());
  int i = min;
  for(; i!=max and std::find(S.begin(), S.end(), i) != S.end() ; ++i);
  return i;
}
```

This is O(nmlogn) in time, but I cannot figure out if there is a more efficient C++ STL way to do this?

*This is not an exercise but I am doing a set of problems for self-improvement , and I have found this to be a very interesting problem. I am interested to see how I can improve this.*

Comment: Can you provide an example? I am not sure I understood what you meant.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/ this?

Comment: @Atomic_alarm , nope that would return 1.

Comment: @jjknuth, why in your example get 3? What will be the result for 3,7,4,2,9 ?

Comment: When you say "efficient", do you mean time-efficient, space-efficient or efficient in terms of programmer working hours?

Comment: @ChristianHackl , time-efficient is usually implied, unless specified otherwise. The programmer working hours are not usually taken into consideration in this context.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm I think 1 is already in the set S , therefore is in the sequence. I am looking for minimum  number not in the set.

Comment: Is this a sequence {1,2,...} which implies it to be ordered ?

Comment: @g24l , you are right, from the example it shows it is a list. I'll correct this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this by building a set of integers and adding larger seen in the set, and holding the minimum not seen in as a counter. Once there is a number that is equal to the latter, go through the set removing elements until there is a missing integer.

Please see below for implementation.

```
template<typename I> typename I::value_type solver(I b, I e)
{
    constexpr typename I::value_type maxseen=
      std::numeric_limits<typename I::value_type>::max();
    std::set<typename I::value_type> seen{maxseen};

    typename I::value_type minnotseen(1);

    for(I p=b; p!=e;++p)
    {
        if(*p == minnotseen)
        {
            while(++minnotseen == *seen.begin())
            {
                seen.erase(seen.begin());
            }

        } else if( *p > minnotseen)
        {
            seen.insert(*p);
        }
    }

    return minnotseen;
}
```

In case you sequence is in a vector you should use this with:

```
solver(sequence.begin(),sequence.end());
```

The algorithm is O(N) in time and O(1) in space since it uses only a counter, constant size additional space, and a few iterators to keep track of the least value.

Complexity ( order of growth rate ) *The algorithm keeps a subset only of the input which is expected to be of constant order of growth with respect the growth rate of the input, thus O(1) in space. The growth rate of the iterations is O(N+NlogK) where K is  the growth rate of the larger subsequence of seen larger numbers. The latter is the aforementioned subsequence of constant growth rate i.e. K=1 , which results in the algorithm having O(N) complexity.* (see comments)

Comment: I have already accepted this answer , but could you please add a bit about the time-complexity of this solution. thanks!

Comment: This algorithm actually is O(*n* log *n*) in time and O(*n*) in space. (You forgot about your `std::set`!)

Comment: @ruakh , I could edit the question if this is sufficient for you with a downsized explanation. I wanted to avoid being pedantic on the analysis of the algorithm.

Comment: @ruakh The set only keeps a subset of the n-sized input (larger numbers), and is therefore O(n+nlogk) in time and O(logk) in space. I assumed k ( size of larger subsequence) to be relatively small, which on average should the expected since the number of recurring subsequences with infinite length in an infinite sequence should not be assumed to infinite ( it has a smaller growth rate) . As you can see the analysis is a bit more complex. To reassure you though, I have tested this.

Comment: @g24l: Firstly -- I think you've misunderstood the terminology. When we say that an "algorithm is O(N) in time", with no further qualification, this means that its *worst-case* complexity is O(*n*). If you mean that your algorithm only has *average-case* O(*n*) complexity, then you should say that. (And it's also worth pointing out that this makes the algorithm suboptimal in terms of time complexity, since there exists a worst-case O(*n*) algorithm.)

Comment: @g24l: Secondly -- I disagree with your analysis. At the end of your function, `seen` will include all values in the vector that are greater than `minnotseen`. We don't have enough information to exactly compute the average size of `seen` (since we don't know how densely packed we should expect the input to be), but if we assume that the input is always equally densely packed, and we vary *n* (such that `minnotseen` and the maximum element of the vector both tend to be proportional to *n*), then even in the *average* case, the final size of `seen` is O(*n*). So: O(*n* log *n*).

Comment: (You can obviously make different assumptions -- for example, you can assume that the input-elements are randomly selected from a small-ish fixed pool, such that `minnotseen` tends to be extremely low for small values of *n*, with its expected value increasing quite quickly as *n* nears the size of this fixed pool -- but if you don't state those assumptions, it's somewhere between "very misleading" and "completely wrong" to claim average-case O(*n*) complexity.)

Comment: @ruakh you are going to much into the details. If the input is dense, then sorting the set is near linear, and the additional space is n in but one case out of n! for that n. The problem is that you think is sizes and operations instead of order of growth. It is common for students to think O(n) means worst case I am going to need storage as much as the size of the input. Instead it means that as n approaches infinite large values, the growth rate of the storage grows with the same rate as the input. That is why that one case does not impact the growth rate. ( really difficult to here)

Comment: @ruakh I have to admit though that it is O(kN) with k-->1 as N-->inf , but I do not intend to go to that depth for an SO post.

Comment: @g24l: Re: "the additional space is n in but one case out of n! for that n": Sure, but even if we (arbitrarily) throw out that one case, there are many cases where it's *n*-1, many cases where it's *n*-2, and so on. In general, it grows proportionally to *n*. (You seem to be thinking that *n* / 2 is O(1), but in fact it's O(*n*).)

Comment: @ruakh (something of n) / n! --> 0 super exponentially fast as n->inf . Which settles this. At any rate thanks for the downvote for no reason whatsoever.

Comment: @g24l: "(something of n) / n! --> 0 super exponentially fast as n->inf": Right, but what hat are you pulling (something of n) / n! from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97094/discussion-between-g24l-and-ruakh).

Comment: @ruakh for every input n that requires comparable to n storage k, there are n! sequences that k is not comparable. As n increases n! Increases much faster.  That is why this is O(1) . Now did I say that I have already tested this? Please do try it out yourself.

Comment: (To give an example of a possible assumption: if the values in the input-vector are randomly, uniformly, and independently selected from the range [1, 2 *n*], then we expect the vector to include, on average, O(*n*) distinct values that are greater than `minnotseen`, resulting in average-case O(*n* log *n*) complexity. So may be making a different assumption, but you haven't said what.)

Comment: @ruakh , the input size is not only unique numbers , since the OP has not specified that, therefore for input size(n) with n the size of input there are infinite size repetitions. e.g. { 1,1,1,4,4,5,5,1,1,1} has a minimum not seen 2 , the associated set has cardinality 4 , and the input size is 10. Thus as n->inf worst case is O(n) and O(1) .

Comment: @ruakh I think this is the case with hash maps etc, the claimed bound amortized cost is constant. There is one case that you get always collisions its O(n). Here this does not happen since the multiples will eventually overtake the (ratio internal storage size) / ( input size ) as (input size) increases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::sort`, and then use `std::adjacent_find`with a custom predicate.

```
int f(std::vector<int>  v)
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    auto i = std::adjacent_find( v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x, int y) 
    {
        return y != x+1;
    } );

    if (i != v.end())
    {
         return *i + 1;
    }
}
```

It is left open what happens when no such element exists, e.g. when the vector is empty.

Comment: What is the complexity of your solution?

Comment: @jjknuth O(n log n): std::sort dominates with O(n log n), std::adjacent_find is linear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use algorithm the standard template library c ++ to work in your code.

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
```

this `std::sort` in algorithm:

```
std::vector<int> v={9,2,5,1,3};

std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());

std::cout << v[0];
```

I hope I understand what you, looking.

Comment: This returns only the minimum of the current numbers. The question is about those that are not there.

Answer (score 0):

Find the first missing positive, With O(n) time and constant space

Basiclly, when you read a value a, just swap with the S[a], like 2 should swap with A[2]

```
class Solution {
public:
/**    
 * @param A: a vector of integers
 * @return: an integer
 */
int firstMissingPositive(vector<int> A) {
    // write your code here
    int n = A.size();
    for(int i=0;i<n;)
    {
        if(A[i]==i+1)
            i++;
        else
        {
            if(A[i]>=1&&A[i]<=n&& A[A[i]-1]!=A[i])
                swap(A[i],A[A[i]-1]);
            else
                i++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(A[i]!=i+1)
            return i+1;
    return n+1;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data are sorted first:

```
    auto missing_data = std::mismatch(S.cbegin(), S.cend()-1, S.cbegin() + 1,
                                      [](int x, int y) { return (x+1) == y;});
```

**EDIT**
As your input data are not sorted, the simplest solution is to sort them first:

```
   std::vector<int> data(S.size());
   std::partial_sort_copy (S.cbegin(), S.cend(), data.begin(), data.end());
   auto missing_data = std::mismatch (data.cbegin(), data.cend()-1, data.cbegin()+1,
                                      [](int x, int y) { return (x+1) == y;});
```